# Its giving me error missing right paranthesis

Tags: sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqdzL.png)List the top 5 companies (in terms of shareholder trade volume) on the New York Stock Exchange.  Display the company name, shareholder trade volume, the current price and the percentage change for the last price change, and sort the output in descending order of shareholder trade volume.  The sample data in the database contains information for only 3 companies but your query must continue to list only the top 5 companies even when there is data for more companies.

```
select name, shares
from (
select co.name as company_name,
SUM(t.shares) as shares,
dense_rank() over (order by SUM(t.shares) desc) as dense_rank,
sp.price as current_price,
(SELECT
stock_id,
stock_ex_id,
price,
(price -  lag(price, 1) over(partition by stock_id, stock_ex_id order by stock_id, stock_ex_id) / 100*100) as perc_change
FROM stock_price
ORDER BY stock_id, stock_ex_id)
from trade t
 join company co
     on t.stock_id = co.stock_id
 join stock_exchange se
     on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
 join stock_price sp
     on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
     and sp.stock_id = co.stock_id
where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
group by co.name
) 
where dense_rank <= 5  
order by shares desc;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvUWn.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is *much* simpler than your query suggests.

Comment: ORDER BY stock_id, stock_ex_id - You cannot use `ORDER BY` in Sub Queries. It will results in Error.

Comment: Format your SQL. If you indent code embedded in parenthesis, you will see mismatches immediately.

Comment: The question asked me for percentage change. I have used lag() function. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to give an answer that gives working SQL, but if we *do* give your SQL some formatting, as recommended, we can see several problems:

```sql
select name,
       shares
from (select co.name as company_name,
            SUM(t.shares) as shares,
            dense_rank() over (order by SUM(t.shares) desc) as dense_rank,
            sp.price as current_price,
            (SELECT stock_id,
                   stock_ex_id,
                   price,
                   (price -  lag(price, 1) over(partition by stock_id, stock_ex_id order by stock_id, stock_ex_id) / 100*100) as perc_change
             FROM stock_price
             ORDER BY stock_id, stock_ex_id)
     from trade t
           join company co on t.stock_id = co.stock_id
           join stock_exchange se on se.stock_ex_id = t.stock_ex_id
           join stock_price sp on sp.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id 
                              and sp.stock_id = co.stock_id
     where se.name = 'New York Stock Exchange'
     group by co.name ) 
where dense_rank <= 5  
order by shares desc;
```

Firstly, your outer subquery has no alias. This is why your query is failing; every object in the `FROM` must have a name or alias and your has none.

Then the outer subquery has aggregatiomn, specifically on `shares`, but `name`, and `price` are both outside of an aggregate query but only `name` is in the `GROUP BY`; this'll cause an error. When aggregating columns/expression must either be aggregated or in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Next we have the inner subquery, of which also has the problem of not having an alias; every column in the `FROM` must have a name as well, and your does not. But notice something, I said **column** there; that subquery is returning multiple columns *and* (I assume) rows yet it's in the `SELECT`. A subquery like that, in the `SELECT` can only return a scalar value; that's a single atomic value. Not many columns, not many rows and certainly not many rows *and* columns.

Unfortunately it's impossible to know what you *really* want there, but this at least answers *why* your query is failing.